# Get JSON content from client in NodeJS api server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I want to get the content of a JSON object I'm posting from client with ajax in a nodejs server based.

If I have the following code in the client side:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#form').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        hellodata = {
                id : '1234',
                content: 'hello'
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:3000/savedata",
            type: "POST",
            data : hellodata,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                //data - response from server
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

How can I get the parameters id and content in the server side?

```
server.post("/savedata", function(req, res){
      //I get here after doing the ajax post and I want to show here the content of hellodata json
});
```

thank you!

Comment: you are using `express`?

Comment: yes i'm using express

Comment: You aren't posting JSON. You're posting form encoded data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read `JSON` in your `POST` requests you should use `body-parser`:

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Then add to your server side:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/json
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post("/savedata", function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
});
```

You also have to update your ajax request with following:

```
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify(hellodata),
```

Comment: @Alhar nice, so you can accept the answer if it was helpful